# Удалить из одного файла строки, которые есть в другом файле

Tags: строки, сортировка, текст, grep

Есть два текстовых файла, внутри много цифровых id:

a.txt:

```
1
2
3
4
...
```

b.txt:

```
1
7
8
9
2
3
...
```

Мне нужно **удалить из файла b.txt все строки, что есть в файле a.txt**.

В итоге в b.txt должны остаться:

```
7
8
9
```

Можно ли как-то это сделать через sort или grep или еще как-то?

Comment: grep -v -x -f a.txt b.txt > c.txt
на маленьких файлах работает. а на больших процесс убивается и в c.txt пустой файл.
может через sort можно сделать?

Comment: вот этот вариант вроде работает diff --new-line-format="" --unchanged-line-format="" 2.txt 1.txt > 3.txt